# if $X,Y$ be a random independent variables if $X+Y$ and $Y$ has the same distribution, then $\mathbb{P}[X=0]=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X,Y$ be a random independent variables if $X+Y$ and $Y$ has the same distribution,show that $\mathbb{P}[X=0]=1$.

Comment: If the variance exists one has $Var(X)+Var(Y)=Var(Y)$ and $E(X)+E(Y)=E(Y)$, hence $Var(X)=0$ and $E(X)=0$, hence $X=0$ a.s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let $X,Y$ be a random independent variables if $X+Y$ and $Y$ has the same distribution,show that $\mathbb{P}[Y=0]=1$.

Sorry but there is a typo in the question

If $(X+Y)\stackrel{\text{d}}{=}Y$

Assuming the existence of MGF,  you get

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{Xt}]\mathbb{E}[e^{Yt}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{Yt}]$$

which implies that

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{Xt}]=1=e^{0t}$$

that is

$$\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1$$

not $\mathbb{P}(Y=0)=1$ as stated.

---

So, one of the two:

1. If $(X+Y)\stackrel{\text{d}}{=}X$ then $\mathbb{P}(Y=0)=1$
2. If $(X+Y)\stackrel{\text{d}}{=}Y$ then $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1$

---

EDIT: for the sake of simplicity I used MGF but it may not exist. Thus it is a better choiche to use CF that always exist. The proof is exactly the same.

Comment: How can you assume existence of MGF? I used Ch. functions because it always exists.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy : yes of course you are right. I wanted to point out the typo in the question. See my edits

Comment: I have already modified the question, thank you both for your comments.

Comment: The proof is not the same since characteristic functions may have zeros (unlike MGF's).

Answer (score 2):

Use properties of characteristic functions.

**NOTE**. Variances, means MGFs etc cannot be used since they may not exist.

$Ee^{it(X+Y)}=Ee^{itX}Ee^{itY}$ by independence so

$Ee^{itY}=Ee^{itX}Ee^{itY}$. Fot $|t|$ sufficiently small we have $Ee^{itY} \neq 0$ so we get $Ee^{itX}=1$ for such $t$. This implies that $X=0$ a.s. (not $Y=0$ as stated)

[$E[1-\cos (tX)] =1-\Re \,  (Ee^{itX})=0$ for $|t|<\delta$ implies that $1-\cos (tX)=0$ for $|t| <\delta$. So $X \in \{\frac {(2n+1) \pi} {2t}: n \in \mathbb Z\}$ a.s. for each $t$ with $0<|t|<\delta$. But  $\{\frac {(2n+1) \pi} {2t}: n \in \mathbb Z\}$ and $\{\frac {(2n+1) \pi} {2s}: n \in \mathbb Z\}$ are disjoint if $\frac t s$ is irrational. Can you finish?].

Comment: You should see @tommik's post

Comment: @Hundred-eyes I have edited my answer. Thanks for your comment.